# C# Loop only returning first row from DataTable

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a csv file with 2 columns and 3 rows. The columns are Latitude and Longitude. When I run the below (IronXL) only the first row is returned in the console. I'm sure I am making a simple mistake.

```
WorkBook workbook = WorkBook.LoadCSV("C:\\Test\\Test.csv", fileFormat: ExcelFileFormat.XLSX, listDelimiter: ",");
WorkSheet ws = workbook.DefaultWorkSheet;
DataTable dt = ws.ToDataTable(true);//parse sheet1 of sample.xlsx file into datatable
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) //access rows
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) //access columns of corresponding row
    {
        Console.Write(row[i] + "  ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: `Console.ReadLine();` is waiting for you to press enter. Just remove that line

Comment: @Charlieface thank you. If I do that the console then closes down and I can't see the output. Do I need to amend my options in VS?

Comment: Then put `Console.ReadLine` at the end after the brace, or change your VS options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/882365/visual-studio-2022-console-app-behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved Console.ReadLine(); to the end of the code block as suggested by @Charlieface in the question comments.

```
WorkBook workbook = WorkBook.LoadCSV("C:\\Test\\Test.csv", fileFormat: ExcelFileFormat.XLSX, listDelimiter: ",");
WorkSheet ws = workbook.DefaultWorkSheet;
DataTable dt = ws.ToDataTable(true);//parse sheet1 of sample.xlsx file into datatable
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) //access rows
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) //access columns of corresponding row
    {
        Console.Write(row[i] + "  ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```